# Pasting images into a RTF in Experience Manager

Tags: experience-manager, rtf, image

Is there are way to modify the behavior when pasting an image in a RTF using the Experience Manager?

Comment: +1 interesting question and thanks for asking, Vincent. So it looks like you'd want a user to be able to paste an image (from Windows clipboard) with maybe the keyboard shortcut `CTRL`+`P`? I'd imagine we'd need an extension to "detect" the paste, but also create a component and make the link in the RTF.

Comment: Could you elaborate on which behavior you would like to modify and how you would want it to behave?

Answer (score 3):

Potentially the Tridion Event System and/or extensions may help you modify and enhance system behavior, however as Alvin and Peter stated, it would be helpful to know what exactly it is you want to accomplish.

Comment: Hi, I also have this question. My requirement is to change an image or to displace an existing image to a new place inside RTF via XPM. Basically, to add new image/videos inside RTF. How can I achieve the same. I have gone through questions on same on the forum but couldn't get the answer which can help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you'd have to start by intercepting the `Paste` event (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035071/intercept-paste-event-in-javascript)) and then implement the logic around whatever it is you want to achieve. Keep in mind that most browsers disallow access to the clipboard from Javascript, so you won't be able to do anything fancy like manipulate the image before pasting or even checking the image dimensions.